# i am Connecting a Local Kibana Server(ec2 instance) to Amazon ES

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

i am Connecting a Local Kibana Server(ec2 instance) to Amazon ES.so i changed the configuration like kibana_index: ".kibana" elasticsearch_url: "http://elasticsearch_domain:80"  but i am not getting kibana page in browser . can anyone help me on this

Comment: "http://elasticsearch_domain:80"???? do you change 9200 port?

Comment: kibana default port is 5601

Comment: please share the logs

Comment: Join kibana, es config (part about elasticip) + check kibana is started...

Comment: will you please clearly explain join kibana es config means